# How to block access to domains with DNS66?

Tags: dns, url, call-screening

I'm using the [open source Android app DNS66](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.jak_linux.dns66/) to block ads on my smartphone. Is it possible to block entire domains (like facebook.com, twitter.com) with it too? My goal: Nothing loads if I visit e.g. facebook.com in the mobile chrome browser.

Comment: Yes you can, see this tutorial....https://sensorstechforum.com/fully-block-ads-android-device-using-dns66/